# Issue with return URL Authorize issue MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written an application in MVC4 and deployed to the server.

I am having an issue whereby when a user tries to navigate to a url that has the [Authorize] attribute `locally` this redirects the user to.

```
/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fEvents%2fCreateEvent
```

However on the server I am finding that this is adding some extra characters to the start of the url?

```
/~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fEvents%2fCreateEvent
```

This is throwing a 404 exception due to the `/~/`

When the user is authenticated and navigates to `Events/CreateEvent` then this works correctly, however fails when they are not!

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the web.config for the forms authentication setup.

Might look a bit like this.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Try removing the tilde `~`