# MVC redirect inserts web root into URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When my MVC4 web site (mywebsite.com) is deployed (to Amazon Web Services) and a non-authenticated user clicks on a link requiring authentication (e.g. Search), they are redirected to

> www.mywebsite.com/**Web.UI_deploy**/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fSearch

instead of

> www.mywebsite.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fSearch

(**Web.UI_deploy** is the web root on the web server). This issue only occurs with deployment, not on localhost.

What is the cleanest method of resolving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor change in the web.config solves the issue

> Before
>
> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
> </authentication>
> ```

I removed the tilde ~ and it solved the problem

> After
>
> ```
> <authentication mode="Forms">
>       <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
> </authentication>
> ```

I got this idea from [Issue with return URL Authorize issue MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229850/issue-with-return-url-authorize-issue-mvc4?rq=1)

Comment: can you provide what your original web.config looked like in the original post? This will help anybody else if they experience the same problem. Your answer may have helped resolve your issue, but doesn't help another user later